# How to recognize whether the Done button is clicked in ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use `ActionMode` to select items in a grid. The problem is that I cannot recognize whether exactly the **Done** button is clicked. The only I can is to know that `ActionMode` is finished. But pressing **Back** finishes the `ActionMode` too. 
The desired behavior is to accept selection on **Done** click, and exit `ActionMode` on **Back** press.

I tried to use `ActionMode.setCustomView()` but it doesn't affect the **Done** button. The `Activity.onBackPressed()` is not called when ActionMode is started.

The one solution I've found is to use ActionBarSherlock and get the **Done** button manually:

```
View closeButton = findViewById(R.id.abs__action_mode_close_button);
```

But it works on Android 2.x-3.x only, because on 4.x a native action bar is used.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Please don't do that as it's implementation specific and extremely non-standard.

You can use the `onDestroyActionMode` callback for when an action mode is dismissed.

Comment: I see, but I'm implementing a picker with multiselection support and I thought that the Done button is a best way to accept selection...
Any way, thanks for you answer! It seems like I have to add a menu item for accepting selected items.

Comment: But how can we distinguish from the done button and the back button? I need to implement different actions for those...

Comment: You might be able to intercept `onBackPressed`. Otherwise, you can't.

Comment: @JakeWharton how to distinguish the destruction of ActionMode due to screen rotation or done button . actually i have the a list of ids to add to fav database table , so if the device orientation change i should retain this array and if the user click the done button i should clear it , please help

Comment: @JakeWharton but how about this scenario: I have a fragment with a list view in it, and that fragment is in a ViewPager. Tap and hold starts CAB, and pressing done cancels CAB. Say i'm in the middle of multiselecting things (so CAB is on). When I swipe to another fragment in the ViewPager, naturally I want to remove the CAB so to do this, I finish the actionmode on the first fragment's onPause method and when the user swipes back to that fragment, i start the CAB again. I think i should be able to differentiate dismissing CAB via swipe and via Done so that I can restart CAB onPause

Comment: If you dismissed the action mode then your app should know that it was done via swipe. If you want different behavior file a feature request on http://b.android.com for it. I'm simply telling you the existing behavior.

Comment: @Tanya: A menu item is absolutely the correct way to accept selected items. "Done" doesn't mean "done selecting items now do something" but rather "cancel all selections."

Comment: @JakeWharton thank you for answer. its useful for me.

Comment: my problem is that onDestroyActionMode gets called as soon as the ActionMode is created, therefore I cannot use the BS standard callback. Android sucks

Answer (score 21):

Here is the solution:

```
ActionMode mMode = MyActivityClass.this.startActionMode(some implementation);
int doneButtonId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");
View doneButton = MyActivityClass.this.findViewById(doneButtonId);
doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do whatever you want 
        // in android source code it's calling mMode.finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: just a side note: pay attention that you call `findViewById` from the activity where you started the action mode and not from an other view, or you will get a `null pointer exception`.

Comment: This does not work with ABS on pre-ICS devices like Gingerbread.

Comment: This code is only works on API LEVEL >= 11
You need to add API LEVEL condition:
View doneButton;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
   doneButton = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");
} else {
doneButton = findViewById(R.id.abs__action_mode_close_button);
}

Comment: WARNING: this is an inflexible solution and it is essentially accessing a private API. If Google ever changes the name of action_mode_close_button, this will cease to work.

Comment: This solution works perfectly except on orientation change button looses its click listener. I am not destroying activity on orientation change.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my implementation, and it's a proper hack but it works and I can't really find an alternative to doing something specific when the ActionMode DONE is clicked. I find it really weird that you can't capture this event more elegantly.

Any suggestions to making this slightly less ugly would be greatly appreciated...

In my activity..

```
boolean mActionModeIsActive = false;
boolean mBackWasPressedInActionMode = false;

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    mBackWasPressedInActionMode = mActionModeIsActive && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK;
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
{
    mActionModeIsActive = true;
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
{
    mActionModeIsActive = false;

    if (!mBackWasPressedInActionMode)
        onActionModeDoneClick();

    mBackWasPressedInActionMode = false;
}

public void onActionModeDoneClick();
{
    // Do something here.
}
```

If you are using Fragments with your Activity then some of this code will probably need to be in the Fragment, and the other bits in the Activity.

@JakeWharton (and other ActionBarSherlock users) if you see this on your travels. I'd be interested to know if the above is compatible with ABS as I have yet to integrate ABS with my current project.

Comment: This did work, but I am using action modes in a few places in my project. So I decided to add MenuItems to the action modes and use these as the actual "confirm" items. The main I converted the icon into a dismiss. This makes the code a lot less hacky.

Comment: It looks like this would also detect when normal menu items are clicked, not just when the Done button was pressed.

Comment: @JDJ what makes you think that?

Comment: As for the answer, looks good but it works without mActionModeIsActive as well: instead just be sure to set `mBackWasPressedInActionMode = false` in onCreateActionMode and then remove the `&&` in `dispatchKeyEvent` so it's just the second test.