# Action Mode Done Button

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an action mode the displays  when  the user select items on the `ListView` now when the user hit the Done button on the Action mode i want to make a specific  action , i make this and it works perfectly , now i want to support the landscape orientation so i should maintain the action mode . the problem that my action against the selected items in the

```
onDestroyActionMode
```

so when the user have select item and rotate the action mode called the   `onDestroyActionMode` and i dont want it when rotating , how to customize the done button event handling so i dont relay on the `onDestroyActionMode`

Comment: what have you tried so far.... try to modify Activity tag in manifest.
in configChanges.

Comment: I'm on the same boat. I want a certain action on the Ok button, but not on rotation or Back button.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check these answers

[Prevent to cancel Action Mode by press back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725729/prevent-to-cancel-action-mode-by-press-back-button)

[How to recognize whether the Done button is clicked in ActionMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642877/how-to-recognize-whether-the-done-button-is-clicked-in-actionmode).

I ended adding the code for the "Done" button into the method onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) and ovveriding the method dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) to catch the "Back" button