# Contextual Action Mode custom behavior

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, contextual-action-bar

In android developer's [menu guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) it is mentioned that:

> The action mode is disabled and the contextual action bar disappears when the user deselects all items, presses the BACK button, or selects the Done action on the left side of the bar.

Technically, it means that `mActionMode.finish()`, the `BACK` button press, or the `Done` action selection call `ActionMode.Callback onDestroyActionMode()` method.

My question is how to perform a custom action (for example `Toast("Action mode exit by Done select")`) when the user selects `Done`, and another action (for ex. `Toast("Action mode exit by BACK")`) when the user press `BACK`?

Comment: Monitor the current state of the CAB(open/not open) and the number of selected items in the list and you could determine which method was used to close the CAB.

Comment: Alexiosdev answered to a similar question [here][1].

 [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14090730/836413

Answer (score 2):

One approach you can take to solving this problem is using a Theme to hide the done button from action modes you create. Then, you simply add your own Done button to every action mode you create. Obviously then you can track whether `onDestroyActionMode` was called because of your done button being hit or by the back button. Here is a Theme that you could apply to the activities that you need to accomplish this with.

```
 <style name="HideActionModeCloseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/NoCloseButton</item>
</style>

<style name="NoCloseButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:visibility">invisible</item>
</style>
```