# What is a reliable way to hide the 'Done' text for a Contextual Action Bar in Android?

Tags: android

Android adds in a check mark and the word DONE, when you're in contextual action mode.

Apps like Gmail seem to have been successful in doing so.
They just display the check mark,

I read a couple of posts here that it's at the android level and hence you cannot, but I'm not sure. Is there a reliable enough solution found as yet?
I just want to hide the text string, not the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

"One approach you can take to solving this problem is using a Theme to hide the done button from action modes you create. Then, you simply add your own Done button to every action mode you create."

```
 <style name="NoCloseButton"      
 parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ActionButton.CloseMode">
 <item name="android:visibility">invisible</item>
 </style>"
```

-[Contextual Action Mode custom behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730404/contextual-action-mode-custom-behavior)

---

In my opinion you could just monitor the state of CAB and determine which method closed the CAB. In theory you could just remove all but one method of closing it.